# I have data in an SQL table in one format now I wanted to insert it into another table but with different format

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I Have sample data in a table with the format of

```
column names: Key, Value, Id
Key         Value     Id
FirstName   Amir      11
LastName    Imtaiz    11
Age         25        11
FirstName   Zohaib    12
LastName    Hassan    12
Age         26        12
FirstName   Mahyu     13
LastName    Sultan    13
Age         24        13
```

Now I want to insert it in another table with following format.

```
Column names Id, FirstName, LastName, Age
Id  FirstName       LastName        Age
11  Amir            Imtaiz          25
12  Zohaib          Hassan          26
13  Mahyu           Sultan          24
```

I am unsure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can conditional aggregation by `id`.

```
SELECT id,
       max(CASE
             WHEN key = 'FirstName' THEN
               value
           END) firstname,
       max(CASE
             WHEN key = 'LastName' THEN
               value
           END) lastname,
       max(CASE
             WHEN key = 'Age' THEN
               value
           END) age
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY id;
```